How do I add a search function to my react app?
I am trying to add a search page to my react app. I want it to have an input box, a search button and after inputting something it will show the whole dataset where the data is. So if I search "Jane Smith for example I want it to give me the whole line of Jane smith's details from the different collections in my database:
Arrest ID
3721538
Arrest Date
2023-07-22T14:45:00.000+00:00
Arresting Officer
"Officer Johnson"
Suspect Name
"Jane Smith"
Offence
"Vandalism"
I have 3 collections in my database and would like the search to fetch data from the collections. I didn't figure out how to use the MongoDB Atlas search so I tried to fetch the data from the pages that display the data in my app:
here are my attempts :
here is an extract from my backend code :
app.get('/api/search', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const searchQuery = req.query.q;
    // Connect to MongoDB
    await connectToMongoDB();

    // Search all collections for records matching the query
    const vehicleRecords = await client.db("aless").collection('vehicle_records').find({ $text: { $search: searchQuery } }).toArray();
    const arrestRecords = await client.db("aless").collection('arrest_records').find({ $text: { $search: searchQuery } }).toArray();
    const crimeReports = await client.db("aless").collection('crime_reports').find({ $text: { $search: searchQuery } }).toArray();

    // Combine search results from all collections
    const searchResults = [...vehicleRecords, ...arrestRecords, ...crimeReports];

    res.json(searchResults);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during search:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error during search' });
  }
});

I don't get any result when I look for something and get this error: "Error during search" in the console.
Is there a way to solve this? How do I proceed from here?
Thank you for the help!
This is the error in the server:
Connected to MongoDB
Error during search: MongoServerError: text index required for $text query
    at Connection.sendCommand (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:281:27)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.command (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:304:26)
    at async Server.command (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:169:24)
    at async executeOperation (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:126:16)
    at async FindCursor._initialize (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\find_cursor.js:55:26)
    at async [kInit] (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:454:27)
    at async next (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:514:13)
    at async [Symbol.asyncIterator] (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:160:34)
    at async FindCursor.toArray (C:\Users\momon\program\my-aless-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:273:26) {
  errorResponse: {
    ok: 0,
    errmsg: 'text index required for $text query',
    code: 27,
    codeName: 'IndexNotFound',
    '$clusterTime': {
      clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1713777560, i: 1 }),
      signature: [Object]
    },
    operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1713777560, i: 1 })
  },
  ok: 0,
  code: 27,
  codeName: 'IndexNotFound',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1713777560, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64('fTs93PA/cG4eV1eaXx9qh0aYOTs=', 0),
      keyId: new Long('7343629009340596229')
    }
  },
  operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1713777560, i: 1 }),
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

I have attempted to make text indexes bit it still doesn't work:
app.get('/api/search', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const searchQuery = req.query.q; // For text fields
    const searchQueryInt = parseInt(searchQuery); // For numerical fields

    // Connect to MongoDB
    await connectToMongoDB();

    // Search all collections for records matching the query
    const vehicleRecords = await client.db("aless").collection('vehicle_records').find({
      $or: [
        { $text: { $search: searchQuery } },
        { "Registration ID": searchQueryInt }, 
        { "License Plate": searchQuery },
        { "Make": searchQuery },
        { "Model": searchQuery }, 
        { "Year": searchQueryInt }, 
        { "Color": searchQuery }, 
        { "Owner": searchQuery } 
      ]
    }).toArray();

    const arrestRecords = await client.db("aless").collection('arrest_records').find({
      $or: [
        { $text: { $search: searchQuery } },
        { "Arrest ID": searchQueryInt }, 
        { "Arrest Date": searchQuery }, 
        { "Arresting Officer": searchQuery }, 
        { "Suspect Name": searchQuery }, 
        { "Offence": searchQuery } 
      ]
    }).toArray();

    const crimeReports = await client.db("aless").collection('crime_reports').find({
      $or: [
        { $text: { $search: searchQuery } }, 
        { "Crime ID": searchQueryInt },
        { "DateTime": searchQuery }, 
        { "Location": searchQuery }, 
        { "Crime type": searchQuery }, 
        { "Last outcome category": searchQuery } 
      ]
    }).toArray();

    // Combine search results from all collections
    const searchResults = [...vehicleRecords, ...arrestRecords, ...crimeReports];

    res.json(searchResults);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during search:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error during search' });
  }
});



"Error during search" If that's the server side log, it should be followed by the error itself (since you wrote console.error('Error during search:', error);). Do you see such an error?

I added the error code I get when I preform the search in node server.js


Error during search: MongoServerError: text index required for $text
query

The error says an index is required for $text.
Please see the following action log reproducing the same issue, and getting resolved by creating a text index.

The statement line 1 tries to perform a full text search but fails since there is no text index existing.

The statement line 2 creates a text index on four keys a, b, c and d.

The statement line 3 succeeds and produces results since there is now a text index supporting this search.
 // Using MongoDB:       7.0.2
 // Using Mongosh:       2.1.1

 use test
 test> t = db.test
 test> t.drop(); // optional step
 test> t.insertMany([{a:"A"},{b:"B"},{c:"C"},{d:"D"}]);
 {
   acknowledged: true,...
 }

 test> t.find();
 [
   { _id: ..., a: 'A' },
   { _id: ..., b: 'B' },
   { _id: ..., c: 'C' },
   { _id: ..., d: 'D' }
 ]

 // line 1
 test> t.find({$text:{$search:'AA DD'}}); 
 MongoServerError: text index required for $text query

 // line 2
 test> t.createIndex({a:"text",b:"text",c:"text",d:"text"}); 
 a_text_b_text_c_text_d_text

 // line 3
 test> t.find({$text:{$search:'AA DD'}}); 
 [
   { _id: ..., a: 'AA' },
   { _id: ..., d: 'DD' }
 ]




So I create an index that contains the fields that I have in my collection? Like this : collection.createIndex(     {       'Arrest ID': 'text',       'Arrest Date': 'text',       'Arresting Officer': 'text',       'Suspect Name': 'text',       'Offence': 'text'     } Do I add this to my backend ?

@RoseMo, As you now know, the index object was missing, very specifically - it was missing from the collection of the database of the MongoDB instance of the application. It has now been in place. Now the application must be performing without the same issue.
Now for application packaging, deployment and maintenance, It is a common practice that the backend application itself would host and run the script for creating database objects including - collections, indexes and any other database objects.

However, there will be cases wherein the creation of database objects separated from backend applications and handled by its own module. This is for very large applications having a significant amount of database objects and major schema changes necessitating schema migration.
